# Delete specific duplicated punctuation from string

Tags: python

I have this string `s = "(0|\\+33)[1-9]( *[0-9]{2}){4}"`. And I want to delete just the duplicated just one  `' \ '`, like I want the rsult to look like `(0|\+33)[1-9]( *[0-9]{2}){4}`.

When I used this code, all the duplicated characters are removed:
`result = "".join(dict.fromkeys(s))`.

But in my case I want just to remove the duplicated `' \ '`. Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution using the re module:

```
import re
s = r"(0|\\+33)[1-9]( *[0-9]{2}){4}"
s = re.sub(r"\\(?=\\)", "", s)
print(s)
```

I look for all backslashes, that are followed by another backslash and replace it with an empty sign.

Output: `(0|\+33)[1-9]( *[0-9]{2}){4}​`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to remove just one \, and not both

Comment: @dinarobert I changed my answer a bit. Do you have a situation, where you have to replace multiple \\ to \? If not, this should work. Let me know if you need it for multiple occurrences.

Comment: @dinarobert in case you are interested, I changed the answer such, that it can handle an unlimited number of double-backslashes and reduces them to single backslashes.

Comment: thank you, that's exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

The function you need is `replace`

```py
s = "(0|\\+33)[1-9]( *[0-9]{2}){4}"
result = s.replace("\\","")
```

**EDIT**

I see now that you want to remove just one `\` and not both.
In order to do this you have to modify the call to `replace` this way

```py
result = s.replace("\","",1) # last argument is the number of occurrances to replace
```

or

```py
result = s.replace("\\","\")
```

**EDIT of the EDIT**

Backslashes are special in Python.

I'm using Python 3.10.5. If I do

```py
x = "ab\c"
y = "ab\\c"
print(len(x)==len(y))
```

I get a `True`.
That's because backslashes are used to escape special characters, and that makes the backslash a special character :)
I suggest you to try a little bit with `replace` until you get what you need.

Comment: This solution is obviously much better than mine :D Interesting how a snippet in the answer can bias somebody so much, that I totally forgot about replace.